# Django Forms Not Rendering In HTML

Tags: django, django-forms

I am finding it difficult to show django forms in html template. The django form fails to render in the template. I am using class base view and below are  my codes for views.py,urls.py, models.py and the html template:

**views.py**

```
class Home(CreateView):
     models = Blog
     queryset = Blog.objects.filter(publish = True)
     template_name='index.html'
     fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('', Home.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
Continent = (
     ('select continent', 'Select Continent'),
     ('africa', 'Africa'),
     ('europe', 'Europe'),
     ('north america', 'North America'),
     ('south america', 'South America'),
     ('asia', 'Asia'),
     ('australia', 'Australia'),
     ('Antarctica', 'Antarctica'),   
)

 class Blog(models.Model):
     name= models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     company= models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     post = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
     author= models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
     mantra= models.CharField(max_length = 200, help_text='make it short 
                              and precise')
     continent = models.CharField(choices= Continent, default= 'select 
                               continent', 
                               help_text='help us to know you even more', 
                               max_length=50)
     publish = models.BooleanField(default =True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self): # new
       return reverse('post_detail')
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
 <body class="loading">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="bg"></div>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="main">

             {{form.as_p}}

             {% include "partials/_footer.html" %}
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
{% endblock %}
```

**Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.**

Comment: It's `model = Blog` not `models = Blog`

Comment: @dirkgroten: I'm a bit surprised that Django does not derive the model from the `queryset`. Since one can access that with `some_queryset.model`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem true. just realised that as well. It should, since `model is None` be able to get it from the `queryset`. So the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Can you check in your browser the source code of your page? Do you actually see the `<div id="main">`?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your timely reply. I did change models to model as advised by dirkgroten; but the issue is still same. And also i can see <div id="main"> in my browser  source code

Comment: I see the form in the browser source code but i have no idea why it is not rendering.

Comment: You see the form in the browser source code? Show us the source. Note also you should add the `<form>` tags yourself (and the `csrf_token` if your form is using `post` method).

Comment: Hi, @dirkgroten thanks again for your reply. Kindly click : http://filesharing24.com/d/DmQ to see a screen capture of by browser source code

Comment: Now please check in your browser tools what css is applied to your "loading" class (and maybe #wrapper and #main ids). Everything is fine as code is concerned, probably you have css that hides one of the wrapping divs. You can also just select the <form> and look at the computed css. Check for the `display` property.

Comment: @dirkgroten you are definitely right. A CSS class was the culprit. A big thank you.

Comment: Also an immerse thank you to @Willem Van Onsem for his contributions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add csrf token to your template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
 <body class="loading">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="bg"></div>
        <div id="overlay"></div>
        <div id="main">
             {% csrf_token %}
             {{form.as_p}}

             {% include "partials/_footer.html" %}
        </div>
      </div>
  </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikrant_Chauhan for your message. I added it as said but still same request.Thanks.

Comment: It shows no error. The django form won't just render in the template. But i can seen the form in the browser source code. Here is a snapshot of it : http://filesharing24.com/d/DmQ

Comment: File at the link is not opening, did you make a modelform for the model? where is forms.py?

Comment: An immerse thank you @Vikrant Chauhan. The issue is now resolved. A CSS class was the culprit. Thanks.